# WordPress adds superfluous </p> to qtip2 content. Cause Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, qtip2

I’m developing a wordpress plugin using qtip2.

Line breaking are not working. 
When trying to create an in-memory div via a JS code following 
[HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

The JS file should add the  htmlDecode function code:

```
function htmlDecode(value){
  return JQuery('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

But unfortunately I'm getting "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" since WP adds a superfluous

```
 </p>
```

and the post's code breaks (from chrome DevTools):

```
return jQuery(("</p>
<div/>").html(value)).text();             } });
```

Please advice

Comment: don't understand how this can get generated like that unless the code is being run through a WYSIWYG editor or something in wordpress admin.

Comment: Hi,The code is being run through a JS file which called by the plugin PHP file

Comment: Actually not very clear at all what the issue really is. Can you create a demo that replicates it

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the Javascript version of htmlDecode

```
function htmlDecode(html){
    var a = document.createElement( "a" );
    a.innerHTML = html;
    return a.textContent; 
   };
```